# I have errors related to my npm build and start not finding my build script and my node version not matching the global verision

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

So I am trying to get react router to work and I hace just created and index.jsx file.

Looking at the terminal in Visual Studio shows 0 errors, yet when I try to npm run build I get a very simple error message: npm ERR! missing script: build

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wanam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-10T17_16_26_320Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\wanam\OneDrive\Desktop\COLL\Collabo\functions>
```

I have gotten this message before and solved it, but those issues always had a more complex error log while this is oddly simple (and my package.json code has not changed for awhile)

When I try to npm start I get this error log:
npm start

```
> functions@ start C:\Users\wanam\OneDrive\Desktop\COLL\Collabo\functions
> npm run shell


> functions@ shell C:\Users\wanam\OneDrive\Desktop\COLL\Collabo\functions
> firebase functions:shell

!  Your requested "node" version "12" doesn't match your global version "14"
i  functions: Loaded functions:
No functions emulated.
PS C:\Users\wanam\OneDrive\Desktop\COLL\Collabo\functions>
```

I posted these together in case the underlying problem is related. I really don't see why the build script is being determined as missing, but here is the package.json code:

```
{
    "name": "collabochat",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^2.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
     },
    "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
   "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
      ]
      },
     "devDependencies": {
     "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
     "typescript": "^4.1.3"
      }
      }
```

Comment: Is `functions` the root of your project where the `package.json` is? If not, is there a nested package.json in the `functions` directory?

Comment: The second message is likely because your machine's Node version doesn't match what you have in your Firebase config, but that's only a warning, it shouldn't be breaking the build — it looks like you don't have any functions set up.

Comment: @ZacAnger I am  not entirely sure how to check, but I did cd.. Collabo to go back one space in my directory and now it says missing toket: from firebase.initializeApp({

Comment: Did that fix `npm run build` at least? It sounds like you have some firebase config issues which should probably go in a separate question.

Comment: @ZacAnger Not sure if it fixed it, at the very least I am no longer getting the missing script build which is good but another error message I will post about. npm start seems to be fixed as it brings me to a local host where it tells me to fix the problem. Thank you

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `functions` has its own package.json, but the project root with the correct npm scripts was one directory up, as addressed in the comments.